# Purpose of ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

For what reason does *ServiceSecurityContext* contain a *WindowsIdentity* property?

Namely, if user is authenticated using windows authentication mechanism, then both *ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity* and *ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity*  properties hold exactly the same information, and if user is authenticated using some other authentication mechanism, then *ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity* will hold blank identity.

Thus, in first case  *WindowsIdentity* property holds the same data as *PrimaryIdentity*, while in the second case it holds no data at all ( ie it holds blank identity ).

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Namely, if user is authenticated using windows authentication
>   mechanism, then both ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity and
>   ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity properties hold exactly the
>   same information

Just plain wrong.

`ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity` returns the type `WindowsIdentity` and `ServiceSecurity.PrimaryIdentity` returns the type `IIdentity`. The `WindowsIdentity` type has a lot more properties than `IIdentity` which help give you more insight, if you need it, into the access rights, claims, tokens, and identity of the authenticated user.

The token in particular can help you impersonate a user and thereby gain access to a privileged resource.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details.